# I want to up to my xampp server a image with Objective-C

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I want up to my server one image from a gallery or from a camera with Objective-C,

I have tried to find that in Google and I find a lot of things but anything for me!

How I do that?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your question.

Comment: I want choose a image for a gallery or for my camera and save to mysql sever (xampp) @ClausBönnhoff